# Existe alguma maneira de ver as publicações apagadas de determinado usuário?

Tags: suporte

Esses dias aconteceu de me deparar com uma pergunta meio complicada (mal explicada, etc.) que acabei votando pra fechar. Não sei se ela foi fechada ou não, mas pouco tempo depois tive a impressão de ter visto exatamente a mesma pergunta sendo publicada novamente. Quando entrei no perfil do usuário, vi que só tinha uma publicação e percebi que só podemos ver as publicações que não foram excluídas ao entrar no perfil de alguém.

Eu gostaria de saber se temos alguma forma de encontrar publicações excluídas (usuários não-moderadores), principalmente porque, se eu já foi comentado pro AP que a publicação pode ser fechada e ele fez esse "drible", pouco vai adiantar comentar de novo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderadores podem ver. O próprio usuário pode ver. Outros usuários com reputação suficiente (10K) podem ver. Esses últimos não verão uma listagem no perfil do usuário. Ele pode ver a postagem se estiver na página dela, mas não tem como localizar facilmente.

Comment: Acabei de testar usando o `deleted:yes` e funcionou. Deveria ter pensado nisso antes. De qualquer forma, obrigado.

Comment: Para mim, que não sou moderador, embora tenha mais do que 10K de reputação, isso retorna o mesmo que `user:me deleted:yes`, independente do número que coloque após `user:`. Colocando `user:18246 deleted:yes` só mostra as minhas postagens deletadas (sou o user 132, o user 18246 é o @jbueno). Bigown, você tem certeza que buscar/listar postagens deletadas de outros usuários não é algo que apenas moderadores podem?

Comment: O @VictorStafusa tem razão, pela busca só é possível encontrar suas próprias postagens excluídas. Só moderadores podem buscar as de outros usuários.

Comment: Bem notado @VictorStafusa. Inclusive, aparece uma mensagem "*Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content*"

Comment: @VictorStafusa a resposta original eu falei que não sabia e pedi para testar, o jbueno disse que funcionou e eu mudei a resposta. Se não funciona, mudo de novo.

Comment: @bfavaretto então não-moderadores só conseguem ver perguntas deletadas se tiverem o link, certo?

Comment: @jbueno Se tiver o link e pelo menos 10K de reputação ou for uma pergunta que você mesmo postou. Quanto a respostas suas em perguntas deletadas dos outros, **acho** que só se estiver naquele link de "perguntas deletadas recentemente" ou "respostas deletadas recentemente" e for recente (não sei exatamente qual período de tempo é considerado recente).

Comment: @jbueno É isso que o Victor disse, precisa ter 10k e o link da pergunta.